# Strip directory structure in HTML

Tags: php, regex

I have a PHP application that reads in a bit of HTML. In this HTML there may be an img tag. What I want to do is strip the directory structure from the src of the image tag e.g.

```
<img src="dir1/dir2/dir3/image1.jpg>
to 
<img src="image1.jpg">
```

Anyone have any pointers?

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: regex is not good html parser - but if you are determined to use it you can use this (assuming your img tag is well formatted and uses double quotes): `preg_replace("/src=\".+\/(.+)\"/",'"$1"',$string)`

Answer (score 0):

As a suggestion, rather than using regex, you may be better off using something like the SimpleXML class to traverse the HTML, that way you'd be able to find the img tags and their src attribute then change it easily. Rather than having to try and parse a whole document with regex. After you've done that you'd be able to just explode the string using the "/" delimiter and use the last value of the exploded array as the src attribute.

PHP.net's SimpleXML Manual: http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

Comment: tried this but the xml parser wont parse my html - <p>hello<img src="/home/miller/Koala.jpg" alt="" width="1024" height="768" />This is a test</p>

Answer (score 0):

This is a tutorial how to change all links in a HTMl document: [Scraping Links From HTML](http://www.a-basketful-of-papayas.net/2009/09/scraping-links-from-html.html).

With a slight modification of the example, this could do it:

```
<?php
require('FluentDOM/FluentDOM.php');
$html = '<img src="dir1/dir2/dir3/image1.jpg">';
$fd = FluentDOM($html, 'html')->find('//img[@src]')->each(
  function ($node) use ($url) {
    $item = FluentDOM($node);
    $item->attr('href', basename($item->attr('src')));
  }
);
$fd->contentType = 'xml';
header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo $fd;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try this with regexp this could work:

```
$subject = "dir1/dir2/dir3/image1.jpg";
$pattern = '/^.*\//';

$result = preg_replace($pattern, '', $subject);
```

Comment: This doesnt seem to be working - The result of the replace is p> from text <p>hello<img src="/home/miller/Koala.jpg" alt="" width="1024" height="768" />This is a test</p>

Comment: This only works with the content of src not the whole HTML. So you would have to extract the content in src and pass it. Look at the comment by Billy Moon his regexp might work like you want it to. But using regexp on HTML is a bad idea as it is not always well formed.

Comment: What would you suggest rather than regexp?